# How to call the variables (length,breadth,height) from another class constructor

Tags: java

How to call the variables (length,breadth,height) from another class constructor

trying to call the variables length,breadth,height from class A

unable to do so

```
   class A {
            int length;
            int breadth;
             int height;
        A(int length,int height,int breadth)
        {
            this.length=length;
            this.height=height;
            this.breadth=breadth;
        }   

    }

    class B extends A
    {      
            public void display()
        {
            System.out.println("Length of the rect is "+length);
            System.out.println("Height of the rect is "+height);
            System.out.println("Breadth of the rect is "+breadth);
        }

    }
    class Inheritence
    {
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            new A(5,6,7);
            new B().display();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `new B()` creates a new instance, which knows nothing about the `A` you created on the line before

Comment: Describe _unable to do so_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A objA = new A(5,6,7)` - makes an object called `objA` and sets properties `length`, `breadth` and `height` to `5,6,7` respectively.

`B objB = new B()` - makes an object called `objB` with new properties `length`, `breadth` and `height` and doesn't set them at all, so there is nothing to display.

If you want to set the values to properties of class `B`, make the constructor in class `B` and assign the values to fields `length`, `breadth` and `height` which are inherited from `A`.

Answer (score 2):

> I trying to call the variables length,breadth,height from class A

No you probably want to use variables from an A **instance**.

I think that what you need is a copy constructor defined in `B` that takes as parameter a `A`.

So define it in `B` such as

```
public B(A a){
   super(a.length, a.breadth, a.height);
}
```

And now you can do :

```
A a = new A(5,6,7);
new B(a).display();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to do:

1. Change the access modifier to protected (read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html))
2. Create a constructor in B that sets the values for these parameters, e.g.

   `public B(int length, int breadth, int height) {
       super(length, breadth, height);
   }`

Once done, `B` will have access to these members and you will be able to print the values.

Comment: If all classes are in the same package, 1. is not needed

Comment: can we pass the values to A constructor like new A(5,6,7) and then using extends keyword calling those values in B class

Comment: @Jay Yes, you can. You will need to change the access modifier as it won't work if the classes are in different packages.